# Is it possible to set the preview image for an Android Wear watch face dynamically?

Tags: android, wear-os

Typically, the preview of a watch face is set through the wear module's manifest; e.g.:

```
<service
    android:name=".AnalogWatchFaceService"
    android:label="@string/analog_name"
    android:allowEmbedded="true"
    android:taskAffinity=""
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
        android:resource="@xml/watch_face" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview"
        android:resource="@drawable/preview_analog" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview_circular"
        android:resource="@drawable/preview_analog_circular" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        <category
            android:name=
            "com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.WATCH_FACE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

My watch face has a selection of backgrounds, and I think it would be neat to show the last selected background in the preview. Can `com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview` and its circular counterpart be set programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately we do not provide this option at the moment. But I will file a bug for improving this.

Comment: Thanks for the official response, Filip. If you have an issue number, I'd like to track it.

Comment: We don't have a public tracker. I will update the bug if/when we make a change.

Comment: Do you happen to have an update? Is it possible now?